# A simple log of a dataframe in python : Error : 'type' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, logarithm

I am trying to take a log of a dataframe and copy it into a new dataframe in Python and I  get this error : 'type' object does not support item assignment

```
import math
y = pd.DataFrame
y['Number'] = np.log(df.Number)
y
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right now you're setting y to the DataFrame class, not an instance of it. You need to call the constructor to create a new dataframe:

```
y = pd.DataFrame()
```

then your assignment should work